# Looking for an elegant LINQ query, alternative to SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

This is a simple question but I'm struggling to find an elegant solution. Let's say I have a simple data structure, the list of groups of items. Each group has a unique ID and each item has a unique ID, too.

I want to obtain a given item from a given group, if it exists, or `null` otherwise. I've come up with two implementations, neither of which I really like:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId;
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId;
    public Item[] Items;
}

public static class Test
{
    public static Item GetItemV1(this IEnumerable<Group> groups, int groupId, int itemId)
    {
        return groups.SelectMany(g => g.Items)
            .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == itemId);
    }

    public static Item GetItemV2(this IEnumerable<Group> groups, int groupId, int itemId)
    {
        var group = groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.GroupId == groupId);
        if (group != null)
        {
            return group.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == itemId);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can it be done as a one-liner query, yet without redundant iterations of `SelectMany`?

Comment: What exactly is redundant in `GetItemV1`?

Comment: "neither of which I really like" why not? What is it that you dislike?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (CodeReview).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, `GetItemV1` would combine (flatten) all items first, even from groups which do not match `groupId`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently your first option doesn't check for the group ID, but that's easily fixed:

```
return groups.Where(g => g.GroupId == groupId)
             .SelectMany(g => g.Items)
             .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == itemId);
```

Or if there's only going to be one group with a given ID, and you want to stop if you've found that group but not found the item:

```
return groups.Where(g => g.GroupId == groupId)
             .Take(1) // Don't look through other groups after finding one match
             .SelectMany(g => g.Items)
             .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == itemId);
```

Comment: The OP states "if it exists" which means this will give a null reference error if groupId doesn't match.

Comment: @DavidG: No it won't. Which bit of this do you think tries to dereference a potentially null reference? Both of my code snippets will return `null` if there's no such item. (Calling `SelectMany` on an empty sequence returns an empty sequence...)

Comment: @JonSkeet, if all groups are unique, can I use `.Select(g => g.Items)` instead of `SelectMany`?

Comment: @avo: No, because you want to flatten the result to a sequence of items, not a sequence of sequences of items. SelectMany is appropriate where.

Comment: What i like is that an exception is prevented by using `Take(1)` instead of `First`/`FirstOrDefault`, sometimes i forget that it is a good way to keep the query "flowing" and to prevent multiple execution.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ain't LINQ great? It's the toolset that keeps on giving.